# subscript out of range error in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Can someone look at the below script and tell me why it's throwing this error subscript out of range error in vbscript ..In the text file there are two entries it writes to the file correctly but then it throws an error while exiting the loop so it never calls the other function..I think it's trying to run 3 times but there are just 2 entries in the text file

```
The text file is in this format

    Format.css Shared
    Design.css Shared


Dim strInputPath1
Dim txsInput1,txsOutput
Dim FSO
Dim Filename

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strOutputPath = "C:\txt3.txt"
Set txsOutput = FSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputPath)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True

Set f = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\spadmin\Desktop\Main\combination.txt")
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  tokens = Split(Trim(re.Replace(f.ReadLine, " ")))
  extension = Split(tokens(0),".")
  strInputPath1 =  "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\files\" & tokens(1) & "\" & extension(1) & "\" & tokens(0) 
  Set txsInput1 = FSO.OpenTextFile(strInputPath1, 1)
  WScript.Echo strInputPath1
  txsOutput.Writeline txsInput1.ReadAll

Loop
WScript.Echo "Calling"

txsInput1.Close
txsOutput.Close
f.Close
Call CreateCSSFile()


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Merge Css Files
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub CreateCSSFile()
 WScript.Echo "Called"

 Dim FilenameCSS

 Dim strInputPathCSS
 Dim txsInputCSS,txsOutputCSS
 Dim FSOCSS


Set FSOCSS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strOutputPathCSS = "C:\txt4.txt"
Set txsOutputCSS = FSOCSS.CreateTextFile(strOutputPath)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\s+"
re.Global  = True

Set fCSS = FSOCSS.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\spadmin\Desktop\TestingTheWebService\combination.txt")
Do Until fCSS.AtEndOfStream
  tokensCSS = Split(Trim(re.Replace(fCSS.ReadLine, " ")))
  extensionCSS = Split(tokensCSS(0),".")
  strInputPathCSS =  "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EpsShared\c\" & tokensCSS(1) & "\" & extensionCSS(1) & "\" & tokensCSS(0) 
  Set txsInputCSS = FSOCSS.OpenTextFile(strInputPathCSS, 1)
  txsOutputCSS.Writeline txsInputCSS.ReadAll

Loop
fCSS.Close
txsInputCSS.Close
txsOutputCSS.Close
Set FSOCSS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your file contains trailing blank lines, applying Split() may return arrays with less than 2 elements. In that case `token(1)` should throw a 'subscript out of range' error.

You should **always** check, if Split() workes as expected:

```
tokens = Split(Trim(re.Replace(f.ReadLine, " ")))
If 1 = UBound(tokens) Then
   extension = Split(tokens(0),".")
   If 1 = UBound(extension) Then
      strInputPath1 =  "..." & tokens(1) & "..." 
   Else
      ... parse error ...
   End If
Else
   ... parse error or just trailing blank lines? ...
End If
```

Comment: This worked..U r so fast in answering and the last time also u helped me..Thank U very much

Comment: Depending on the actual requirements you could also ensure that there's always at least *n* tokens by appending *n-1* delimiter characters, e.g.: `Split(str & "..", ".")` will split `str` in 3 or more tokens.

Comment: What about this one?


  Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  defaultprn = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device")
  arrPrnStr = Split(defaultprn,",")
  fullPrinterString = arrPrnStr(0)
  arrFullPrnStr = Split(fullPrinterString,"\")
  shortPrinterName = arrFullPrnStr(Ubound(arrFullPrnStr))
  defPrinteri.InnerHTML = shortPrinterName
  defPrinteri.title = fullPrinterString